# Laravel 8: Passing Factory properties into children relationships

Tags: laravel, nested, relationship, factory

we are currently working on a laravel 8 application. We are trying to create factories to create some dummy data for manual / developer based application testing.

The current code of my main Database-Seeder is below:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UserTableSeeder::class,
        ]);
        \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
        \App\Models\Activity::factory(5)->create();

/* 1. try
        $tenFact = \App\Models\Tenant::factory(2)->has(
            \App\Models\Project::factory(2)->state(
                function (array $attributes, \App\Models\Tenant $tenant) {
                    return ['tenant_id' => $attributes['id']];
                } 
            )->hasTasks(5)->hasLocation()
        )->hasContracts(3)->create();

        */
        
/* Currently being used: */
        \App\Models\Tenant::factory(10)->has(
            \App\Models\Project::factory(5)->hasTasks(5)->hasLocation()
            )->hasContracts(3)->create();

    }
```

ProjectFactory.php:

```
class ProjectFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Project::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Projekt: '. $this->faker->name,
            'budget' => $this->faker->randomDigitNotNull*1000, 
            'progress' => $this->faker->randomDigitNotNull*10, 
            'budget_used' => $this->faker->randomDigitNotNull*50, 
            //'tenant_id' => Tenant::factory(),
            'location_id' => Location::factory()->hasTenant(1),
        ];
    }
}
```

LocationFactory.php:

```
class LocationFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Location::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Standort: ' . $this->faker->company,
            'street' => $this->faker->streetName,
            'house_number' => $this->faker->buildingNumber,
            'house_addition' => $this->faker->secondaryAddress,
            'zip' => $this->faker->postcode,
            'city' => $this->faker->city,
            'tenant_id' => Tenant::factory(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Our relationships look like this:

```
Tenant 
  |-- Project (has: tenant_id, but also has location_id)
  |   | -- Task (has: project_id)
  |-- Locations (has: tenant_id)
  |-- Contracts (has: tenant_id)
```

When creating datasets with the above named Tenant-Factory the following happens:

- Tenant->id is being passed to Project(tenant_id)
  but: Tenant->id is not being passend to Location (which depends on the tenants id but is also used for Project).

How can we pass the id of \App\Models\Tenant::factory(10) to  Project::factory(5)->hasTasks(5)->hasLocation()?

Additionally we do have the problem, that even though we request 10 tenants, we will get around 60, because Location/Project create new objects when they should be using existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up using the chained usage of the Tenant-Factory - I finally used some for-Loop that connected the related objects to each user by using laravels for() and state() methods:

```
       for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
            $tenant = \App\Models\Tenant::factory()->hasContracts(3)->create();
            for ($j=0; $j < 5; $j++) { 
                $location = \App\Models\Location::factory(1)->for($tenant)->create();
                $project = \App\Models\Project::factory(1)->state([
                    'location_id' => $location->first()['id'],
                    'tenant_id' => $tenant['id']])->hasTasks(5)->create();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class ProjectFactory extends Factory
{
 $location_ids = App\Models\Location::pluck('id')->toArray();

    protected $model = Project::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Projekt: '. $this->faker->name,
            'budget' => $this->faker->randomDigitNotNull*1000, 
            'progress' => $this->faker->randomDigitNotNull*10, 
            'budget_used' => $this->faker->randomDigitNotNull*50, 
            //'tenant_id' => Tenant::factory(),
            'location_id'=> $faker->randomElement($location_ids),
        ];
    }
}
```

```
class LocationFactory extends Factory
{
    $tenant_ids = App\Models\Tenant::pluck('id')->toArray();
    protected $model = Location::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Standort: ' . $this->faker->company,
            'street' => $this->faker->streetName,
            'house_number' => $this->faker->buildingNumber,
            'house_addition' => $this->faker->secondaryAddress,
            'zip' => $this->faker->postcode,
            'city' => $this->faker->city,
            'tenant_id'=> $faker->randomElement($tenant_ids),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to get this working as it led to Projects that belonged to tenant_id = 1 whilst the containing locations belonged to tenant_id = 2. I've posted a working solution.